# How to display image that is stored in public folder whose path is working fine?

Tags: laravel, laragon

I'm trying to display the image that is stored in my public folder. The path to my image is being displayed when i just use {{$post-> image}} but i cant get the image to be displayed when i run the following command.

```
@foreach($posts -> $post)
      <tr>
                <td> <img src="{{ asset($post->image) }}" alt=""></td>
                <td> {{ $post-> title }} </td>
      </tr>
@endforeach
```

[image: chrome screenshot]
[image: folder screenshot]

Comment: What is the path to your image exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your picture the only path you're calling is public/posts/picture.jpg but also based on your picture you need to call public/storage/posts/picture.jpg so you need

```
{{asset('storage/posts/picture.jpg')}}
```

Comment: it is working fine now but how do you make the picture source link dynamic? like i used {{ $post->image }}

Comment: what do you mean? well just add the needed path before you put it on database or input it normally in your blade. if this answer your question please accept it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: this code helps only for a single image, how do I set the path dynamically? {{asset('storage/$post->image')}} is not working.

Comment: you need to use `@foreach` in blade are you getting the data in your controller and database?

Comment: yes i'm using array , $post is my value. what should be my code? {{ asset('storage/here'}}

Comment: please update your question with the code of your full foreach in blade if you're already using one. If not use `@foreach($arrayorcollection as $data) //html and data value here @endforeach`

Comment: if you do foreach you're still getting one image?

Comment: i just copy pasted your code for and replaced picture with the filename, i tried doing {{asset('storage/posts/$post->image')}} but its not working.